# php can't run command about android

Tags: php, android

I would like to create an android project in PHP. I hv wrote a .bat file for PHP to execute:

```
cd C:\temp
android create project -n test -t 1 -p ./testing -k com.examples.test -a Main
exit
```

(I have tested that these commands are workable if I just type them in cmd.exe.)

However, if I use PHP to run the .bat file with following code:

```
<?php chdir("C:\\");
system("test.bat"); ?>
```

It will be no response at all.
Is PHP not able to execute any command about "android"?
or any better solution for creating project in PHP?

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure but in case you are running this on a LAMP server, I think that you need to escape some characters of the batch file in order to run it.

Answer (score 1):

*.bat file is not a binary executable. I think it can be executed only by system's shell like *.doc file can be opened only by sofware that supports it.

To execute *.bat file you need to execute it via shell's cmd.exe

```
system("cmd.exe /c test.bat");
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `test.bat` file is placed in the file system? The code you are supplied is trying to run it from a root of disk C:.

Comment: Sorry that i hv a typo mistake that the first line of bat is "CD C:\temp"

Comment: BTW, if I just double-click the .bat outside PHP website, it can success to create an android project. Why I can't run this bat in PHP?

Comment: Are you are running it through the browser?

Comment: yes, also if i change the content of .bat to the simple command (like "dir"), it can run in PHP :( i don't know why php can't read android command in bat

Comment: I think the environment, in what `system` is invoked, have a PATH variable which is not containig path to android.bat file. Or maybe it didn't contain PATH variable set at all. Try to specify full path to android.bat in your test.bat file.